# What Solr field type provides basic wildcard searches?

Tags: solr, wildcard

I posted a document with the field value "Pineapple upside down cake."  I want to get hits for `pineapple`, `pine*`, `*side`, `pi?????le`, `upside down`, etc.  I chose `text_en` which does not find `*side` nor `pi?????le`.

What *out of the box* field type will give me hits for all the above?

I'm using Solr 7.6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to retain all the tokens as is (as I commented on your previous question about this, the `text_en` type contains a stemmer), use a field type with just a WhitespaceTokenizer and a LowercaseFilter. You'll have to define this field yourself.

I'm guessing you can use `text_general` to get a decent enough answer (it uses the StandardTokenizer, so it'll split on a few more cases than just whitespace).

The reason is that wildcard searches happens without most processing taking place (as it's impossible to do proper handling of stemming, splitting, etc. when you don't have the complete token), so any wildcard search will be against the generated list of tokens after processing.